# Sidekiq worker can't access the test database in Rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

When I was trying to run a `Rspec` test, the sidekiq worker always use the development database instead of testing database. Here is my code.

The Rspec test file:

```
it "Student can get latest status after looking for prioritized tutor" do
  post api_v1_students_request_look_for_prioritized_tutor_path,
     { subject: 'nothing' },
     { "AUTHORIZATION" => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.
       encode_credentials("remember_token2")}

  p Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.first
end
```

The print result for

```
 p Sidekiq::Worker.jobs.first
```

is

```
.[Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass, [{"class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'Listener::Studentlistener'\n- :public_send\n- - publish_student_state\n  - 2\n"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"f26083779b943283b5389c47", "created_at"=>1441042790.1108208}, {"class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'Listener::Requestlistener'\n- :public_send\n- - publish_request_creation\n  - 1\n"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"b7eca603bb1c7e6199751435", "created_at"=>1441042790.1343408}, {"class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'Listener::Tutorlistener'\n- :public_send\n- - publish_request_creation\n  - 1\n"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"102ed2f8419364864dd1fa8e", "created_at"=>1441042790.1346662}, {"class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'Listener::Studentlistener'\n- :public_send\n- - publish_student_state\n  - 2\n"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"10b97c57f7bb3a53b82609bb", "created_at"=>1441042790.298615}, {"class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'Listener::Requestlistener'\n- :public_send\n- - publish_request_creation\n  - 2\n"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"a2c382b66a2036265b76f13d", "created_at"=>1441042790.3033404}, {"class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'Listener::Tutorlistener'\n- :public_send\n- - publish_request_creation\n  - 2\n"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"2e623670a35ac05ffa993287", "created_at"=>1441042790.3036788}]]
```

which means `sidekiq` get all the works. However, the sidekiq worker use the development database instead of testing database, so it can't find the right record in the testing database and my test will fail. Anyone know how to fix it?

my `database.yml` file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 3933
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: TWS_Server_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: TWS_Server_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: TWS_Server_production
  username: TWS_Server
  password: <%= ENV['TWS_SERVER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

and my `spec_helper.rb` file

```
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require 'factory_girl'
  require 'sidekiq/testing'
  require 'wisper/rspec/matchers'


  Sidekiq::Testing.fake!

  RSpec.configure do |config|

    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

    config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

      expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
    end

    config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
      mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
    end

    config.include(Wisper::RSpec::BroadcastMatcher)
    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      begin
        DatabaseCleaner.start
        FactoryGirl.lint
      ensure
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: What's on your `config/database.yml`?

Comment: Can you show your test helper file? I suppose it's name is `rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: @jlhonora you can check the file now. Thank you!

Comment: @dimakura you can check the file now. Thank you!

Comment: Does it work if your remove the `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'` line?

Comment: @jlhonora sorry, it doesn't work. The sidekiq can't receive any jobs if I remove the `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'`.